# How to concatenate separately declared modifiers?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
val modifierA = Modifier.size(100.dp)
val modifierB = Modifier.background(Color.Red)
```

How do you create a `modifierC` that is the concatenation of A and B?

I tried using `.apply` and `.also`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`composed`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#composed) function:

> Declare a just-in-time composition of a Modifier that will be composed for each element it modifies

Something like:

```
Box(modifierA.composed{ modifierB })
```

or

```
val modifierC = modifierA.composed{ modifierB }
Box(modifierC) {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Modifier.then`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier.Companion?then(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier)#then(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier))

> Concatenates this modifier with another.

```
val modifierA = Modifier.size(100.dp)
val modifierB = Modifier.background(Color.Red)
val modifierC = modifierA.then(modifierB)
Row {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .then(modifierC)
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .then(Modifier.size(100.dp))
            .then(Modifier.background(Color.Green))
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
    )
}
```

These three modifiers are equivalent, excluding color.

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work for me. Are you sure that works?

Comment: I've added a sample to try out, not sure how this could not work