# How to combine multiple Modifier objects in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable that passes a `Modifier` instance to its child composable as follows:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        content = content,
    )
}
```

This adds the `fillMaxWidth` modifier to the `modifier` argument. However, this is not the desired behaviour because I would like `fillMaxWidth` to be the default width, but still allow the caller to override it.

How do I combine/merge the two modifiers while making my local modifiers the default?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103556/how-to-concatenate-separately-declared-modifiers

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989659/when-do-you-need-modifier-composed/65084372#65084372. If you want to chain `Modifier` just use `Modifier.then`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`Modifier.composed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#composed) function.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    OtherComposable(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().composed { modifier },
        content = content,
    )
}
```

Comment: This is a wrong way to use Modifier. composed for merging modifier purpose, as @Aman kappor mentioned, you can easily use the Modifier.then(otherModifier).
Modifier.composed declares a just-in-time composition of a Modifier that will be composed for each element it modifies. composed may be used to implement stateful modifiers that have instance-specific state for each modified element, allowing the same Modifier instance to be safely reused for multiple elements while maintaining element-specific

Answer (score 33):

You can simply use `Modifier.then(otherModifier)`.
Note: Order is important and you might want to consider what you are adding yourself and what you are adding from outside.

`composed` is used for stateful modifiers like when you want to implement custom touch controls where you will be called every-time anything changes.
See [Composed Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).composed(kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1))

Comment: Doesn't work with size at least
Example:
*val customModifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Red)

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.Green)
            .then(customModifier)
    )*

Background color was changed to Red, but size still as `fillMaxSize`

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`Modifier.then`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#then) function.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    OtherComposable(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().then(modifier),
        content = content,
    )
}
```

Comment: No, it is not correct. Try to use for example: `Modifier.fillMaxWidth().then(Modifier.width(100.dp))`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti wouldn't the Modifier.width(100.dp) be passed in from outside, so that *would* be correct?